# Delimiter problem in data validation list formula

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to add a data validation list in the target-cell, based on the target-value. But I think there is a problem with the language.

The idea is to write the value you want as the average value followed by a [Space] and then the number of steps in each direction. ( e.g. "1,3 2")

With the following code I get the list but formatted as text(with a period-sign). If I remove the "Replace("-bit I get integers only, and if I exchange the delimiting comma to a semicolon it's anarchy.

```
Private str$, i As Integer, qty As Integer, avrg As Double, s As Double
```

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    With Target
        If .Value Like "* *" Then
            qty = Mid(.Value, InStr(1, .Value, " ") + 1, 10)
            avrg = Mid(.Value, 1, InStr(1, .Value, " ") - 1)
            s = avrg - (0.1 * (qty + 1))
            For i = 1 To qty * 2 + 1
                str = str & ", " & Replace(s + (i * 0.1), ",", ".")
            Next
            .Validation.Delete
            .Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, Formula1:=str
            .Validation.ShowError = False
            .NumberFormat = _
"[Blue][<" & avrg & "] ""Easy- ""0.0;[Red][>" & avrg & "]""Hard - ""0.0;""Average - ""0.0"
            .Value = avrg
            str = ""
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Is it possible to temporarily turn of some translation-sequence or something

Manually comma is the delimiter to decimal points and semicolon the delimiter for the items. I would write 1,1;1,2;1,3;1,4;1,5 in the source-box and get the following correct result in the List:

pos1 `1,1`

pos2 `1,2`

pos3 `1,3`

pos4 `1,4`

pos5 `1,5`

Comment: Could you share some sample data?

Comment: @Jitendra Singh Not sure what you mean by that, This is supposed to be applicable to any workbook, sheet and cell. When entering "1,3 2" the expected result would be a list with 1,1 to 1,5. The actual result is a list with 1.1 to 1.5 and a failing numberformat since it's recognised as text.